# -d option for split is illegal on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I have bash script that works on Ubuntu but for OS X 10.9 i get the 
error for split command:

```
split -b 1000000 -a 3 -d $F $F && rm $F || { echo "Error: 'split' command not installed" ; exit 1 ; }

split: illegal option -- d .
```

According to the split man page, `-d` is

```
   -d, --numeric-suffixes
          use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic
```

Is there workaround for this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [GNU version of split](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) is different to the [OS X version of split](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/split.1.html).

OS X is based on BSD Unix, and Linux (often referred to as GNU/Linux) uses the GNU toolset.

The GNU version of split is part of the [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), and the good news is that these are available in MacPorts. If you have [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) installed, you can install the **coreutils** port using the command:

```
sudo port install coreutils
```

This installs the GNU core utilities (including split) with a `g` prefix, so you call split using the command `gsplit`.

Comment: While I know it is possible to install the coreutils with the default names, I would never recommend it since all scripts written for OS X assume that the BSD tools have the 'original' names.

Comment: The coreutils are also available via homebrew (also with a 'g' prefix): `brew install coreutils`

Comment: @ScottEarle well you shouldn't write bash for OSX. Regardless you can get around that by using an alternate shell on iTerm and loading a separate bash_aliases file, leaving the system one alone